# How to specify custom container for lambda in AWS Cloud Formation Template

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a java lambda function that requires access to a special non-java executable.

I've seen from the AWS docs that I can use a custom image (based on the java11 image) for my lambda function. My plan is to build an image that includes the special executable. The AWS docs describe how to do this and upload the image to ECR. However, I'm unclear about how I actually deploy my lambda using this custom container. At present the lambda is deployed using a cloud formation template that looks something like:

```
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: My lambda function
      Handler: com.foo.MyLambdaFunction::handleRequest
      Runtime: java11
      etc...
```

Am I supposed to edit the `Runtime` property? If so, to what? Do I need to deploy my lambda in a completely different way?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom runtime identifier, which is specified on the bottom of [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html).

If you are willing to use SAM, take a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/building-custom-runtimes.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the speedy reply. Are you saying that I should use 'provided' as the value for the 'runtime' property? The AWS docs don't appear to allow this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-runtime

Comment: The link you provided lead me to this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-images.html#configuration-images-cloudformation . This suggests that I need to set 'PackageType' and 'Code' properties - and perhaps not specify a 'runtime' at all?

Comment: I've edited my answer with some additional information, maybe this helps you.